# Rails Cancan - How to Restrict Users From Accessing Custom URL Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cancan

I have a custom route setup that has a location_id in the url (see below)

```
resources :menu_items, :path => "/location_menu/:location_id"
```

So when I hit `/location_menu/1` it will show me location_1's menu, `/location_menu/2` will show location_2's menu, etc.

Each user is associated to multiple locations (`has_many :locations`)

I am trying to use cancan to restrict users from viewing certain menu_item URLS.

**For example:** User 1 is associated with location 1 and 2. So they can only view the page `/location_menu/1` and `/location_menu/2`. But they would not be able to view `/location_menu/3`.

I created a custom method as a before_filter in my **controller**:

```
before_filter :location_check
 ... 
def location_check
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
  authorize! :see_location, @location
end
```

In my **ability.rb**

```
can :see_location, MenuItem do |location| location && user.location_ids.include?(location.id) end
```

For some reason, this does not work for me. What could I be doing wrong? If you guys could help me, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: does the association between `user` and `location` is `has_many_through`

Answer (score 1):

Check once within ability.rb,

```
user.location_ids.each do |l|
  can :view, MenuItem, location_id: l
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not seeing what benefit you get from defining a custom route rather than either a nested resource, but it looks likes its inflating your domain language and resulting in a situation where any particular resource could be referred to by several different names - this will probably become confusing enough that it's worth it to simplify now.

In your `location_check` method, you are authorizing `see_location` on a `Location` instance, but the portion of the `Ability` class you've shown us concerns a `MenuItem` class. Try defining your ability like this:

```
can :see_location, Location, id: user.location_ids
```

**Edit**

If you need a cancan action to authorize `MenuItems` directly, try this (assuming a `belongs_to :location` relationship on `MenuItem`):

```
can :view, MenuItem, location_id: user.location_ids
```

As for your routes, think even simpler. All you need is this:

```
resources :location_menus
```

...and then everything related to this goes in a `LocationMenusController`. Don't worry that there's no model by the same name - you still can still lookup your locations with `Location.find(params[:id])`. From what I understand, everything about the location menu pages hinges around the current user's access to a particular location, so you can treat `LocationMenu` as a kind of virtual resource wrapped around `Location`.

Comment: Hey, that totally makes sense. However I am not authorizing Locations, instead I am authorizing MenuItems based on their location_ids.

Comment: So for the routes, were you thinking something like this? 

`resources :locations do
    collection do
      scope path: ":id" do
        resources :menu_item_locations
      end
    end
  end` 

so the URL would be /locations/1/menu_item/:id. How would you lock down a location & the menu_item id at the same time?

Comment: I think so, I will try this out later today and let you know!